# How to add values from an array of objects using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects (cart), the size of which can change, and I need to write a function to add the all the values of a key (itemPrice).

I have tried iterating through the array based on the array length with a for loop, but I don't know how to just add all of the values of that certain key together. I always end up just adding the first value to itself for the length of the array.

My array looks like :

```
[ { itemName: shoes, itemPrice: 12 }, { itemName: socks, itemPrice: 34 }, { itemName: shorts, itemPrice: 56 }
```

My for loop looks like:

```
function total() {
    var total=0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= cart.length; i++) {
        total += cart[i]["itemPrice"] + cart[i]["itemPrice"];
        return total;
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be 102, but the total is 24. I know why it's 36, it's just adding the first itemPrice to itself 3 times, I just don't know how to get it to add the itemPrice values to each other.

EDIT: Yes, I meant I am getting 24, not 36.

Comment: you're returning after first iteration itself, i doubt you're getting `36` you must be getting `24`

Comment: also, you need to loop from zero to length-1

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am getting 24

Answer (score 1):

You could skip the manual looping and use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead.

```
const total = cart.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.itemPrice, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer

```
var cart = [ { itemName: "shoes", itemPrice: 12 }, { itemName: "socks", itemPrice: 34 }, { itemName: "shorts", itemPrice: 56 }];

function total() {
    var total=0;
    for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        total += cart[i]["itemPrice"] ;//+ cart[i]["itemPrice"];
        // return total;// this is wrong it will exit the loop so you need to remove it
    }
    return total;
}
console.log(total());
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you, I'm very new to coding and my brain is pretty fried right now from school!

Comment: Welcome to the world for coding :) If it works please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, for example:

```
const cart = [{itemName: shoes, itemPrice: 12 }, { itemName: socks, itemPrice: 34 }, { itemName: shorts, itemPrice: 56 }];

const total = () => {
    const checkProp = cart.prototype.map(e => return e.itemPrice).reduce((a, b) =>{return a + b;
    }, 0);
   return checkProp;
}
```